# Node - Console.log printing multiple times

Tags: node.js, console.log

I have a piece of code, just printing a variable using `console.log` and Node is printing the output multiple times. Any idea what may be the issue?

```js
var router = express.Router();

var isJob = true;
console.log(isJob) // Five times output is getting printed

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: are you running multiple instances of your server?

Comment: update your answer with your code